# Windows Update on Windows 7 Kb2712808 will not install

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

This update will not install through windows update, with error code 8007065E -windows update encountered an unknown error.

I'm an admin on the machine, its Windows 7 Pro, 32bit.

Windows update "Get Help with this error" link provides no further details.
I've tried to run the Windows Update fix tool, this found no issues.

The event log shows a number of errors over time regarding connectivity to Windows Update service, but other updates have installed fine.

The Windows Update reset tool tells me:
[image]

any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: minus comment please?

Comment: My guess: "Lack of research effort".  What have you tried already? Have you tried resetting Window Update?  Anything in the log files?

Comment: how do you reset windows update? Will add some additional details

Comment: From MS: [How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058)